# Difference in map operation between parallel and sequential Scala collections

Tags: multithreading, scala, collections, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am coding a little Scala snippet to test the difference in performance of parallel and procedural Scala collections on my machine using an personal Java image processing code that I am refactoring.
However, I encountered a strange issue with the use of map over a parallel collection (ParArray in this case): the calculation doesn't seem to kick off (The program doesn't halt neither enter into the getBrightness def). It seems that I enter a blocking state.

Here is the code :

```
def getBrightness(bright: Array[Float], kernel : Array[Array[Float]], kernelSize : Int, normFactor : Float, x : Int, y : Int) : Float = {
    var brightness : Float = 0
    for(dx <- -(kernelSize / 2) to kernelSize / 2){
      for(dy <- -(kernelSize / 2) to kernelSize / 2){
        val kerVal = kernel(kernelSize / 2 + dx)(kernelSize / 2 + dy)
        brightness += bright(index(dx + x, dy + y)) * kerVal
      }
    }
    brightness / normFactor
}

  def convolute(pixels : ParArray[Color], kernel : Array[Array[Float]]) : ParArray[Color] = {
    val bright : Array[Float] = pixels.map(c => Color.RGBtoHSB(c.getRed, c.getBlue, c.getGreen, null)(2)).toArray

    val normFactor : Float= kernel.toList.flatten.sum
    pixels.zipWithIndex
          .map{case(_ , idx) => getBrightness(bright, kernel, kernel.length, normFactor, idx % imgWidth, idx / imgWidth)}
          .map(Color.getHSBColor(0, 0, _))
}
```

It is definitely an issue with my understanding of parallel collection as, if I change the collection into a sequential array like this :

```
  pixels.zipWithIndex
          .seq //switching to sequential collection
          .map{case(_ , idx) => getBrightness(bright, kernel, kernel.length, normFactor, idx % imgWidth, idx / imgWidth)}
          .map(Color.getHSBColor(0, 0, _))
          .par
}
```

Then everything goes fine and the convolution is performed. I also know that the problem comes from the getBrightness call inside the map as my debugger loop over it and never execute the def itself, i.e. never enters the getBrightness definition. 
Does it come from the accesses over the *bright* array, causing a blocking state ? As I am using it only in a read-only fashion, I believe it is thread safe.
I am a little bit confused...

Comment: There's a class of known issues around starting threads from object's static initializer, resulting in deadlock.https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9076

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I'll investigate the issue !

Comment: Note that for loops can contain multiple generators. You can write the one in `getBrightness` as `for { dx <- ???; dy <- ???; kerVal = ??? } brightness += ???`.

Comment: @som-snytt I read the resource and it is a little above my level of comprehension. However, if I got it right, the issue comes from the use of a lambda expression in a static def of my utils object. I tried to use an instance of a class instead, but the problem remains. How could I get around it ? (PS: I tried adding `scalacOptions += "-Ydelambdafy:inline"` in my build.sbt without any effect)

Comment: Yes that's the idea. Deadlocks are hard, if that's the issue. Maybe it's not the issue.